# how to pull 300-400k data stored in mysql to mongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I was developing a `spring boot` api to pull data from remote `mysql` database table. This table contains 300k - 400k data daily. We need to migrate this data to `mongoDB` now. I tried `GridFS` technique to store collected `json` file to `mongoDB`. I was able to this on local machine. But when I tried this scenario with  live server, the `JVM` threw error :

```
2018-12-18 17:59:26.206 ERROR 4780 --- [r.BlockPoller-1] o.a.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector  : 

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.ArrayList.iterator(ArrayList.java:840) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.updateSelectedKeys(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:496) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.run(NioBlockingSelector.java:339) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]

2018-12-18 17:59:27.865 ERROR 4780 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/datapuller/v1] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded] with root cause

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I tried to exceed the heap size with `-Xmx3048m` by opening `java` utility from control panel.. but same result. What should I do next to resolve this issue. I have not posted code here because I hope it was all fine as it was running OK on local machine with 60k to 70k record data.

Comment: why use spring boot for this?

Comment: then what should i use

Answer (score 0):

The most performant way is always to bypass all those abstraction.

Since you are not locked to Sprint Boot, I will suggest you to dump the data as csv from mysql, either via mysqldump, or

```
echo 'SELECT * FROM table' | mysql -h your_host -u user -p -B <db_schema>
```

Then you can import this csv to MongoDB.

```
 mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 -d database_name -c collection_name --type csv --file csv_location --headerline
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/